# On the performance impact of cycles in a neo4j graph?

Tags: performance, graph, neo4j, cycle, directed-acyclic-graphs

Cycles in a graph come in various forms. They can be short or long.  For example: peter -> bill -> tom -> peter; peter -> peter. Sometimes the presence of a cycle is frowned upon, but sometimes it is necessary to represent your data in that way.

I was wondering what is the impact of the presence of a cycle in a graph (my data) when running a query in Neo4j.

Let's say I have a query for a particular pattern over my data. There can be situation where I have a cycle, and a situation where there is not a cycle in my data. Since, in essence, a cycle is an infinite loop (e.g. if I were running a DFS algorithm, it would keep looping infinitely if I do not take precautions), I presume that the Neo4j DBMS is equipped with the overhead of detecting, and breaking out of these loop.

For this reason, I am lead to believe that there would be a notable performance difference in these situations, i.e. the implication is that having no cycles would lead to better performance of some query.

Am I right to think so? Is this a valid issue or am I exaggerating? Is there any material on this topic in Neo4j?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The tl;dr**

Infinite loops are not possible in Cypher and as such cycles in your graph do not alone pose a problem for query performance.

**The long detailed answer**

This is a great question, and the start of the answer is within the documentation of [uniqueness within Cypher traversals](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/introduction/uniqueness/):

> While pattern matching, Neo4j makes sure to not include matches where the same graph relationship is found multiple times in a single pattern. In most use cases, this is a sensible thing to do.

Though it would be more accurate to say:

> where the same graph relationship is found multiple times in a single **path**

As paths are traversed according to the match pattern, a specific relationship may only be traversed once in that path. Direction of traversal does not matter here. Neither does whether the relationship has a variable assigned to it or if the relationship is part of a variable-length path. Once a relationship is traversed for a single path it will never be traversed again.

This pretty much protects you from infinite loops, which by definition require you to traverse the same relationships over and over.

However this does not protect you from escalating costs when there are a great many multiple paths among nodes due to the permutation of all possible relationships (all unique and never repeating per path) that can be traversed.

For example, if you take the Movies graph from `:play movies` in the Neo4j browser, you can issue a query like `MATCH (n:Person)-[*]-(m:Person) RETURN count(*)` and this will likely never return, as the number of possible paths between any two :Person nodes, due to the permutation of all possible relationships that can be traversed (while not repeating any in each individual path) becoming prohibitively costly (and this being done for all possible combination of two :Person nodes in the graph).

This type of query would lock up Neo4j eventually as the number of paths to evaluate goes astronomical, but again this isn't due to infinite loops.

To get around these kinds of limitations (after all, you may want to use a very similar query to find distinct nodes reachable, or the number of distinct nodes reachable) you would need to change the uniqueness of the traversal from Cypher's 'RELATIONSHIP_PATH' uniqueness to something else.

If you are using the Traversal Framework in Java (which you can use if you are creating a user defined procedure, kernel extension, or using embedded Neo4j), you can change the [uniqueness of the traversal](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/tutorial-traversal/#_uniqueness) to a different behavior.

With regards to avoiding infinite loops, 'NODE_PATH' uniqueness will also prevent them, as it ensures a node may only be visited once per individual path.

One of the most useful that also prevents infinite loops is 'NODE_GLOBAL' uniqueness, which ensures that a node is only visited once total **across all paths**, not just per path. It is this uniqueness that is best used when you want to find all distinct nodes (or count all distinct nodes) reachable from a starting node, and as such we make use of 'NODE_GLOBAL' uniqueness within certain [path expander procs](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths) of the [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) library (and when using `apoc.path.expandConfig()` you can explicitly set the uniqueness yourself if you want a different type).

So in summary, by default infinite loops cannot happen using Cypher. Some of the more severe Cypher performance problems you encounter may be related instead to a skyrocketing number of possible paths matching a match pattern, especially with an unbounded variable-length expansion, as this may eat up heap space or otherwise develop into an extraordinarily high number of unique paths to evaluate. Through the traversal API or APOC path expander procedures you can change the traversal uniqueness behavior to the needs of your query.

Comment: So in other words, Neo4j geting stuck in cycles depends on 'uniqueness of traversal' technique which the Neo4j user can configure?

Comment: It's not about cycles at all...it's that the number of possible distinct paths (that don't repeat a relationship per path) can explode, especially if the pattern you have doesn't have an upper bound, and can potentially touch a huge portion of the graph. If this gets into the hundreds of thousands, millions, or billions of possible paths, it's going to take a toll on the heap, and is going to start taking a very long time to process. Depending on what you really want to do, changing the uniqueness of traversal may drastically cut down on the number of paths evaluated during expansion.